# How to make a payment via Paymill using Ruby

Tags: ruby, e-commerce, payment-gateway, activemerchant, paymill

I need to make a payment to [Paymill](http://paymill.com) and I want to be able to achieve this using the Ruby language.

**UPDATE:**

I did publicly release [paymill_on_rails](https://github.com/lgs/paymill-on-rails) on github. It is a Paymill subscription system based on Rails 4.0.0 and [paymill-ruby](https://github.com/dkd/paymill-ruby), running on ruby-2.0.0-p247

See also the [home project](http://lgs.github.io/paymill_on_rails/)

An example application is also deployed on [Heroku](https://paymill-on-rails.herokuapp.com). Please feel free to fork & contribute eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this quite easily using the following steps:

1. Create a new Account at [Paymill](http://paymill.com).
2. Get the public and private key from the Paymill settings page
3. Install the [activemerchant](http://activemerchant.org) gem:

   ```
   gem install activemerchant
   ```
4. I used the following script below in order to make a purchase

Please note that as long as you don't activate your account at Paymill it will run in Test mode. So no money will actually be transferred. They also list [test credit cards](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/testing/) which will never be debited either.

#### The script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_merchant'
require 'json'

# Use the TrustCommerce test servers
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaymillGateway.new(
    :public_key => 'MY_PAYMILL_PUBLIC_KEY', 
    :private_key => 'MY_PAYMILL_PRIVATE_KEY')

gateway.default_currency = 'USD'

# ActiveMerchant accepts all amounts as Integer values in cents
amount = 1000  # $10.00

# The card verification value is also known as CVV2, CVC2, or CID
credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
    :first_name         => 'Bob',
    :last_name          => 'Bobsen',
    :number             => '5500000000000004',
    :month              => '8',
    :year               => Time.now.year+1,
    :verification_value => '000')

# Validating the card automatically detects the card type
if credit_card.valid?

# Capture the amount from the credit card
response = gateway.purchase(amount, credit_card)

if response.success?
puts "Successfully charged $#{sprintf("%.2f", amount / 100)} to the credit card #{credit_card.display_number}"
else
raise StandardError, response.message
end
end
```

Comment: Please, do NOT use this if you don't have the proper PCI certifications. Instead, use the solution suggested by Kryptman . The reason is that Credit Card data should *never* reach your servers, unless you have the appropriate PCI certification. (disclaimer: I work at PAYMILL)

Comment: How can I supply an email and the name of the customer? And how can I make this a subscription?

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing it using a paymill gem from https://github.com/dkd/paymill-ruby

It's really easy to use, just follow the README and you will have an idea of it's possibilities. It also supports subscriptions.

Comment: The readme is lacking a lot of info. For example, how does it handle errors? it's too cryptic