# How to supply name and email to Paymill payment

Tags: activemerchant, paymill

I am creating a Rails 3.2 application where I use Paymill to handle payments.
I can make one off payments using Active merchant. The problem with this is I cannot find a way to send the name of the buyer and the email address so the Paymill Client is incomplete. Also I would like to be able to create a Paymill subscription using Active merchant. Is this possible?

I know there is a Javascript version of the payment system and it works. Problem is I do not want to use Javascript, only ruby.

I have used this guide: [How to make a payment via Paymill using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089973/how-to-make-a-payment-via-paymill-using-ruby)

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Please, do NOT use Active Merchant if you don't have the proper PCI certifications. The Javascript version is the only way to use our service and profiting from our PCI compliance.

That being said, please take a look at the following paymill-ruby-wrapper, which has been provided by a third party developer - maybe it serves your purpose: https://github.com/dkd/paymill-ruby

Best regards,
Julian

(disclaimer: I work at PAYMILL)

Answer (score 0):

Julian is right, you should *not* use ActiveMerchant except if you have the proper PCI certifications. It seems you want to do something like this:

1) Create a client object, passing the name (description) and email as parameters. See this: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#create-new-client

2) Create a payment method object, passing the client as parameter (and the token retrieved by the JavaScript bridge): https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#create-new-credit-card-payment-with

3) Make a new transaction, passing the payment method object: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#create-new-transaction-with

And to create a subscription, you need to have an offer object and a client with a valid payment method: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#create-new-subscription